# countdown to specific date

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got this countdown timer JavaScript code, but it restarts every time I refresh my browser.
I want it to countdown to a particular date, instead.
How can I achieve that?

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 21 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <span class="days"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Near the very end, change the line to something like `var deadline = "2018-04-01T12:00:00-0500"` (noon eastern time on April Fool's)

Comment: Save the current countdown on a cookie or something and when the page is refreshed load it from there to get back to the last countdown.

Comment: @hungrykoala There's no reason to do that if you simply count down to a specific point in time.

Comment: Looks like it counts down to 21 days from load time. Have you tried putting in a specific date there instead? `+ 21 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because each time you refresh browser the end time is the same in case you add 21 days to the current time. So each time you have 21 days interval. To solve this problem set fixed time like `Date.parse('2018-01-11 20:00:00')`.

Comment: Note that the `getTimeRemaining()` already parses the date. It is probably not necessary to parse it twice.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But if you still need to add 21 days... =)

Answer (score 0):

Correct update from @ChrisG

```
 function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        function updateClock() {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

            daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        }

        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }

    var deadline = "2018-01-30T12:00:00-0500";
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```